# VBA Minimum value being 0 [zero] when using a button to minus 1 from cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very basic code which is assigned to a shape which minus's 1 from the value in cell H6. What i cannot figure out is how to stop the cell value going below 0.

I have tried the below where the -1 works but the code keeps faulting due to the minimum value part

```
Sub RoundedRectangle27_Click()

    Cells(6, 8).Value = Cells(6, 8).Value - 1
    IF cell(H6, <=0 Then = 0)

End Sub

Sub RoundedRectangle27_Click()

    Cells(6, 8).Value = Cells(6, 8).Value - 1
    IF cell(H6, <=0 Then = 0)

End Sub
```

I do not want the cell value to go below 0 as i have a VLOOKUP linked to it. Subsequently i also need the value to go no greater than 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` should come first:

```
sub RoundedRectangle27_Click()
    if Cells(6, 8).Value > 0 then
        Cells(6, 8).Value = Cells(6, 8).Value - 1
    end if
end sub
```

That way, no matter *how* hard or fast you pound on `RoundedRectangle27`, it will never go negative.

You can use a similar method for preventing increases to above eight, but you *may* want to think about refactoring for re-use:

```
function AdjustBy(value, delta, clampMin, clampMax)
    if value + delta > clampMax then
        AdjustBy = clampMax
    else
        if value + delta < clampMin then
            AdjustBy = clampMin
        else
            AdjustBy = value + delta
        end if
    end if
end function

sub DecreaseButton_Click()
    Cells(6, 8).Value = AdjustBy(Cells(6, 8).Value, -1, 0, 8)
end sub

sub IncreaseButton_Click()
    Cells(6, 8).Value = AdjustBy(Cells(6, 8).Value, 1, 0, 8)
end sub

sub DoubleButton_Click()
    Cells(6, 8).Value = AdjustBy(Cells(6, 8).Value, Cells(6, 8).Value, 0, 8)
end sub
```

Comment: I tried it in my other code to prevent the number going above 8 when another button is clicked but the code fails?

Comment: Also very helpful. Works perfectly. Thank you